# How to use grpc compression without hurting performance

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a service using grpc (in C++) to stream data to client-side (it's streaming grpc).

For the original implementation, the average throughput could be ~110MBps with a 1Gbps NIC, so I think bandwidth itself is a bottleneck. The usual way is to enable compression/decompression.

I found grpc supports compression natively. The only code I added at server side is

```
builder.SetDefaultCompressionAlgorithm(GRPC_COMPRESS_DEFLATE);
builder.SetDefaultCompressionLevel(GRPC_COMPRESS_LEVEL_LOW);
```

with no change at client-side. But the throughput drops stably.
From the network's behavior, it's ~20MBps.
Calculating from protobuf messages' `ByteSizeLong()`, it's ~26MBps, but still far less than 100MBps.

I also tried for other compression algorithm (deflate/GRPC_COMPRESS_ALGORITHMS_COUNT) and levels (low/medium/high),

Some initial guess might be:
Compression is performed synchronously, and compression rate does match IO throughput, which leads to a bottleneck at server-side.

I intended to investigate whether it supports derived class, so that I could implement my own, but from this [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25156), it seems C++ currently doesn't support it.

I want to know if I'm using grpc compression wrongly, or if there's any work-around for my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that how does server provide the data? After compression, traffic is decreased but it doesn't mean the bottleneck is compression. I'll suggest to profile the performance for data producing and compression.

Comment: @LouisGo The server's data is fetched and sent to client in an asynchronous style: data to be sent is enqueued to an unbounded queue first, then another thread fetches data from queue, and send back to client. So I don't think it affects data generation.

Comment: @LouisGo Also, I just tried on my baseline benchmark server (which generate fake data to send, which is random bytes), I get the same throughput from server to client side. So I think it's compression's issue.

Comment: Just a side note, output compressed data in lower speed doesn't means the performance is decreased. Assume the compression rate is 10:1, then 110Mbps to 26MBps is actually ~2.3 times boost. You must pay cpu resource for compression, so overall traffic speed slow down should be expected.

Comment: @LouisGo From the network's behavior, it's ~20MBps. Calculating from protobuf messages' ByteSizeLong(), it's ~26MBps. For the latter value, it should be decompressed throughput. So I imagine it to be on par or better than uncompressed version.